# Find the cost of leveling the triangular plot.Find the area using Herons formula

Tags: geometry

A Triangular Plot has sides $600$m .$640$m and $700$m.How much would the leveling cost if $1m^2=50$Rs. Solve the Problem using Heron's Formula.

Comment: You have Heron's formula, you have the three sides of the triangle, you have the cost per square meter. What do you possibly need help with?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a cauchy integral problem, but I'll bite.

$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}=\frac{600+640+700}{2}=970$

$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=\sqrt{970(970-600)(970-640)(970-700)}\approx 77781$

$Cost = 77781 × 50 = 3889051$

It will cost Rs. 38,89,051.

Comment: (Digression)If a convex quadrilateral has a circumcircle, that is ,if all 4 vertices lie on a circle,then its area is$[ (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)]^{1/2} $ where a,b,c,d are  the lengths of the sides and s is half the quadrilateral's perimeter.